# Mysql join query taking too much time even though indexes are implemented

Tags: mysql, performance, optimization, query-performance

Hi I have a mysql query

```
SELECT 
    `locationMapping`.`keyId` AS `caseId`,
        `locationMapping`.`id`
FROM
    `locationMapping`
INNER JOIN `locationSubtype` ON (`locationMapping`.`locationSubtypeId` = `locationSubtype`.`id`
    AND `locationMapping`.`locationTypeId` = `locationSubtype`.`locationTypeId`
    AND `locationMapping`.`govtId` = `locationSubtype`.`govtId`)
    AND ((`locationSubtype`.`govtId` = '90')
    AND (`locationMapping`.`keyTable` = 'xercase'))
WHERE
    locationMapping.govtId = 90

GROUP BY `keyId`
```

Taking 8 seconds to execute.

Create table command for locationMapping is: 
    show create table locationMapping;

```
CREATE TABLE `locationMapping` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`govtId` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`locationSubtypeId` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`keyId` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`keyTable` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`locationTypeId` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
`gisCode` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `locationmapping_instance` (`keyId`,`keyTable`),
KEY `locationmapping_subtype` (`locationSubtypeId`),
KEY `locationmapping_govtid` (`govtId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3994710 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Create table command of locationSubType is

```
CREATE TABLE `locationSubtype` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`govtId` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`locationTypeId` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
`description` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
`code` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
`gisCode` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
`sortorder` smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `locationsubtype_locationtype` (`locationTypeId`),
KEY `locationsubtype_govtid` (`govtId`),
KEY `locationsubtype_giscode` (`gisCode`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4319 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Explain statement for query is:

```
id,   select_type, table,             type,  possible_keys,                                                             key,                      key_len, ref,                              rows, Extra
'1',  'SIMPLE',    'locationSubtype', 'ref', 'PRIMARY,locationsubtype_locationtype,locationsubtype_govtid',             'locationsubtype_govtid', '4',     'const',                          '756', 'Using index condition; Using temporary; Using filesort'
'1', 'SIMPLE',     'locationMapping', 'ref', 'locationmapping_instance,locationmapping_subtype,locationmapping_govtid', 'locationmapping_subtype','4',     'comcate_dev6x.locationSubtype.id','333', 'Using where'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this rewrite:

```
SELECT  m.`keyId` AS `caseId`,
        m.`id`
    FROM  `locationMapping` AS m
    WHERE  m.`keyTable` = 'xercase'
      AND  m.govtId = 90
      AND  EXISTS (
        SELECT  *
            FROM  locationSubtype
            WHERE  m.`locationSubtypeId` = `id`
              AND  m.`locationTypeId` = `locationTypeId`
              AND  m.`govtId` = `govtId`
                  )
    GROUP BY  m.`keyId`
```

In many cases `EXISTS()` is faster than `INNER JOIN`.

This 'composite' index is important:

```
locationMapping: INDEX(govtId, keyTable)  -- in either order
```

The Optimizer is smart enough to notice the transitive nature of `govtId=90`, so I removed one mention of it.

**More**

```
AND   `locationMapping`.`govtId` = `locationSubtype`.`govtId`)
AND ((`locationSubtype`.`govtId` = '90')
...        locationMapping.govtId = 90
```

The optimizer, if given the first of those, plus either of the other two, will deduce the final one.  You have provided all 3, which is OK.  But it is 'overkill'.

The first line is important because it tells the optimizer how the two tables are related.

Comment: what do you mean by "The Optimizer is smart enough to notice the transitive nature of govtId=90, so I removed one mention of it.".  Kindly explain

Comment: I added something; hope it helps.